# Create a alias using ls | grep | xargs xdg-open

Tags: bash, alias

I'm trying to create a alias combining `ls | grep | and xargs xdg-open`.

This is what I've tried so far. Not sure why it is not working.

```
alias lso='ls | grep "$1" | xargs -I {} xdg-open {}'
alias lso='ls | grep "$@" | xargs -I {} xdg-open {}'
alias lso='ls | grep | xargs -I {} xdg-open {}'
```

The idea is be able to to this in the terminal:

```
$ lso example
```

The interesting thing is that I can use this using the terminal:

```
$ ls | grep example | xargs -I {} xdg-open {}'
```

Does anyone have any work around that?

Comment: if you need to take arguments, you need a function, not an alias. aliases literally do text substitution, nothing fancier. The only way this would work is if your arguments can go at the end of the line